# Microsoft teams videos are always redirected to microsoft stream

Tags: video, microsoft, video-streaming, microsoft-teams

I have just installed microsoft Teams on my ubuntu laptop. I have also another computer (which has windows) with Teams installed, in this way I can make a comparison.

Unfortunately when I click on video lessons on Teams I get redirected to the microsoft stream associated video lessons (which tipically have a worse video quality). Of course this redirection doesn't happen with my "windows Teams".

My ubuntu version is 20.10.

Is there a way to get my "ubuntu Teams" video lessons directly reproduced on Teams itself?

Comment: Seems like a Teams issue that has nothing to do with Ubuntu which you never said what version of Ubuntu you are using.

Comment: Using windows I don't have this kind of problem. In my class other people have the same issue.